# How does the default Android MMS app handle incoming SMS/MMS?

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, broadcastreceiver, mms

I want my app to be able to send an sms/mms and have my phone react as if it received an actual sms/mms. Is there a way to do this? I have tried making an intent and then broadcasting it, but this didn't seem to work.

```
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
smsIntent.putExtra("address", "1234567");
smsIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi");
smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
smsIntent.setAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");
sendBroadcast(smsIntent);
```

Comment: Do you mean that your app needs to simulate the reception of an SMS? Your phrasing could be clearer (could be me).

Comment: I want my app to send out a broadcast that mimics the broadcast you would receive normally with an incoming sms, if that makes sense. I would want the SMS to be received by the default SMS app still.